# Error while using EasyAdminBundle with my Image entity

Tags: php, symfony

i want to use EasyAdminBundle for my Backend.
I have an Image entity in one-to-one relation with my article entity.
When i try to use the "create article" button of EasyAdminBundle , i have the following error :

```
A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "OAH\NewsBundle\Entity\Image" passed to the choice field. To read a custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired property path.
```

i try to put a A "`__toString()`" method in my Image entity but this doesn't work too.
So anybody know how to fix this please ?

Comment: Is your `toString` function public ? Cleared the cache and meta cache ? (apc..)